# What is 'follow' option in questions?

Tags: support, follow-posts

It seems a new option has been added to questions and it is 'follow'. How does it work? Every comments and edits and answers for one question will send to us if already we had followed it?

Comment: Answered on the global Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cody Gray noted, [Meta.SE has details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network), but the TL;DR here is

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices.

It's simply a more granular way to keep track of questions when you are not directly involved for normal things like comment pings, answers, etc.